# Use logical/binary indexing in Pandas while chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(100), columns=["A"])
```

I can do

```py
df[df.A < 97]
```

Now, imagine I want to apply a similar operation to `df` after preprocessing, such as `df.tail()`, but without modifying `df`.

I will now have to do

```py
df.tail()[df.tail().A < 97]
```

and this get less and less readable (and performant) the more preprocessing I do.

I could do

```py
df_tail = df.tail()
df_tail[df_tail.A < 97]
```

which may be more performant, but is still less readable that I would like.

In Python 3.8, I can also do

```py
(df_tail := df.tail())[df_tail.A < 97]
```

but this is not exactly more readable.

What I am looking for is some way to write

```py
df.tail()[["A" < 97]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.tail().query('A < 97')
```

Output:

```
     A
95  95
96  96
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [selection by callable](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) with lambda function:

```
print (df.tail().loc[lambda x: x["A"] < 97])
     A
95  95
96  96
```

Comment: Thanks. I can only accept one answer, unfortunately - and I prefer the other one as it's shorter and more readable.

Comment: @bers - I have no problem with it, happy coding!